# Rotation and movement in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation

I want to make a minigame where the background (maze) is always rotating around the same point, an immovable playerMC that's in the middle of the stage. To get the rotation I am using two MCs, one parent, that I rotate, and one nested maze that I would like to move  according to mouse/keyboard movement

Unfortunately, the x and y axes on the maze are moved so at 90deg any movement 'up' will change to 'right'.

I do realise sin and cos  or translation matrix should do the trick, but for some reason I can't get it right.

Here is a short gif summarising my problem: http://blackdragonschronicles.strefa.pl/Public/Vertigo.gif
I would greatly appreciate any help in the matter

Comment: You should post your current code so others can find a problem in it and not write the whole thing from scratch

Comment: Would probably be easier to move the player through the maze, then rotate/translate the viewport (a parent/container of everything) to make it look like the player is still.     See my question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879034/scale-position-rotate-parent-object-to-make-child-object-take-up-entire-stage for a similar concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a **Matrix** which solves this pretty nicely.
In my small example I have an movieclip called *box* sitting on the stage. Its pivot is in the top left corner (0,0). If I want to rotate the cube from the center I would first translate the matrix by half of its width and height. I then rotate it by some arbitrary angle, and finally apply the matrix transformation to my box.

```
var angle:Number = Math.PI/64;

var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
m.translate(-box.width >> 1, -box.height >> 1);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
function loop(e:Event):void {
    m.rotate(angle);
    box.transform.matrix = m;
}
```

In the same spirit you could translate a matrix with your current world position. And rotate around that point.

```
m.translate(position.x, position.y);
```

You can learn more about Matrices in AS3 **[here](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/)**.

Comment: What really helped here was the link to learn about matrices :) Thank you very much for that. After understanding what they're about I managed to wthip a piece that I will now post below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link you provided, Iggy, I've managed to understand what and how I want to do it. I used an additional method that was made for situations like this. Here's the code

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import fl.motion.MatrixTransformer;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,eF);

//Set rotation pivot
var RotationAt:Point = new Point(player.x,player.y);
//Center the MC at the player/pivot
mc.x = player.x
mc.y = player.y

function eF(e:Event){
    var my_matrix = mc.transform.matrix;//needs to be refreshed all the time

    MatrixTransformer.rotateAroundExternalPoint(my_matrix,player.x,player.y,1);

    mc.transform.matrix = my_matrix; // changes the rotation
}
```

Later I just needed to add code for ading/subtracting x and y with the mouse current position.

Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Glad that helped. :) Matrices are amazing and solve some tricky problems with out a whole lot of visible trig.