# Flash as3 Pivoting an object round a point

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gravity

In Flash cc, I am wondering how I can make a drag and drop game. But depending on were you drag the object will rotate so gravity will effect it. For instance if you pick up a a piece of paper with your thumb and index at the bottom the paper will rotate so you are holding it at the top. How can I recreate this in flash???

Here is my code so far... (I am a big newbie to flash so please be generous with answers)

```
var drag:Number = 1;
var BlockAppear = new MovieClip;

gotoAndStop(1, "Minigame-Block");

HeartBear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_4);

function fl_ClickToDrag_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    HeartBear.startDrag()
    gravity = 0
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_4);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    HeartBear.stopDrag();
    gravity = 0.9
}

{
    var gravity = 0.9;
var floor = 241.3;
HeartBear.y = 710.9;
HeartBear.speedY = 0;
HeartBear.impulsion = 10;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterframe);
function enterframe(e:Event) {
    HeartBear.speedY += gravity;
    HeartBear.y += HeartBear.speedY;
    if(HeartBear.y > floor) {
        HeartBear.speedY = 0;
        HeartBear.y = floor

    }

}
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, space);
function space(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
        HeartBear.speedY = -HeartBear.impulsion
    }
}
}

Shopclicker.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_3);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop(1, "Shop");
}
```

Comment: Hmm. You're asking for a physics model, if I understand you correctly. How to rotate an object around a point can be found [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/08/04/changing-a-movieclip-registration-point-on-the-fly-with-as3/) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789168/as3-rotate-an-object-around-its-center-point)

Comment: No sorry that's not what I am looking for. I need it so you can interact with it freely not an animation.

Comment: This was just a principle of how to implement rotation. User interface is up to you.