# Rotate object around centre?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a project and need a wheel that rotates with mouse movement, I've made the wheel rotate with the mouse, but it rotates around the corner, not the center.

What code can I add to this to make it rotate around the center?

This is the code I'm using so far:

```
var dx : Number;
var dy : Number;

stage.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkMouse );

function checkMouse( evt : Event ) : void
{
dx = mouseX - rota.x;
dy = mouseY - rota.y;
rota.rotation = (Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 Rotate an object around its center point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789168/as3-rotate-an-object-around-its-center-point)

Comment: Edit the wheel object to move its anchor point to the center of the drawn wheel. Should do.

Answer (score 0):

You'll only ever be rotating an object around its origin, and the origin can't be moved.  However, you can move a child object to rest at the center of its parent's origin.  When rotating the parent, the child appears to move around its own center.

[image]

Programmatically, if `wheel` is a child of `rota`, you'd do the following...

```
wheel.x = -wheel.width/2;
wheel.y = -wheel.height/2;

rota.rotation = (Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI)
```